# How to generate an 11x11 QR-Code

Tags: qr-code

Does anyone know how to generate an 11x11 module QR-code? Alternatively, it could also be a 13x13 code, but preferably 11x11.
I know the codes exist, but I can't figure out how to go about generating my own.
The code doesn't have to store much information. It would be nice with a tiny image, but it wouldn't need more than a simple text message.

I have used online code generators in the past, but most of them requires a paid subscription to customize and make codes, and as my project isn't sponsored, I don't have the budget to pay for the code.

Thanks in advance for all answers

Comment: It's hard to answer this when you haven't indicated which QR-Code library you're using, or even which programming language.  Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: My problem is mainly that I have no propper prior experience with QR codes, or their functionality. I've been using online generators, which allows me to simply upload my piece of content and the code is generated for me (usually hosted by the site that generated the code), but I can find no such generator or website to help me make a 11x11 QR-Code. I wouldn't know how to use codes to make one either. I apologize if I've asked something very stupid, but I honestly don't know what I'm talking about

Comment: Sounds like you just want a program such as `qrencode` or `qtqr`.  I haven't used either; that's just what `aptitude search qr` gives after ignoring anything to do with QR/Cholesky decompositions.  But then it's not a programming question, and probably belongs on [su] instead.

Comment: Alright, thank you! :) and I apologize for the misunderstanding. Have a nice day